# Как добавить шифрование в SHA256 для Basic auth в Spring

Tags: java, spring, криптография, spring-security

Я храню пароли юзеров в базе в зашифрованном виде - SHA256. Использую Basic auth и чтобы сейчас пройти авторизацию, я должен передавать пароль на контроллер тоже в SHA256. Можно ли как то переопределить SecurityConfig, чтобы пользователь мог передать пароль в исходном виде, но под капотом произошло шифрование этого пароля, и Spring сравнил этот зашифрованный пароль с зашифрованным паролем из базы?

Текущая реализация SecurityConfig:

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    private final UserService userService;

    public SecurityConfig(UserService userService) {
        this.userService = userService;
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        InMemoryUserDetailsManager manager = new InMemoryUserDetailsManager();
        userService.getUsers().forEach(user -> manager.createUser(createUserDetails(user.getUserName(), user.getPassword())));
        return manager;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .requestMatchers(EndpointRequest.toAnyEndpoint()).permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and().httpBasic();
    }

    private UserDetails createUserDetails(String username, String password) {
        return User.withUsername(username)
                .password(encodePassword(password))
                .roles("USER")
                .build();
    }

    private String encodePassword(String vaultPassword) {
        PasswordEncoder encoder = PasswordEncoderFactories.createDelegatingPasswordEncoder();
        return encoder.encode(vaultPassword);
    }
}
```

**UPD**: новая версия конфигурации:

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    private final UserService userService;

    public SecurityConfig(UserService userService) {
        this.userService = userService;
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        InMemoryUserDetailsManager manager = new InMemoryUserDetailsManager();
        userService.getUsers().forEach(user -> manager.createUser(createUserDetails(user.getUserName(), user.getPassword())));
        return manager;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .requestMatchers(EndpointRequest.toAnyEndpoint()).permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and().httpBasic();
    }

    private UserDetails createUserDetails(String username, String password) {
        return User.withUsername(username)
                .password(passwordEncoder().encode(password))
                .roles("USER")
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider daoAuthenticationProvider(UserDetailsService userDetailsService, PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder) {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        authProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
        authProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
        return authProvider;
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return PasswordEncoderFactories.createDelegatingPasswordEncoder();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да, можно.

За такое поведение отвечает PasswordEncoder. Логика работы примерно такая:

1. Пароль приходит в открытом виде;
2. Spring Security определяет AuthenticationProvider, который ответственнен за аутентификацию пользователя для данного метода API. В Вашем случае это DaoAuthenticationProvider;
3. DaoAuthenticationProvider шифрует пароль с помощью PasswordEncoder и делегирует поиск пользователя экземпляру UserDetailsService;
4. UserDetailsService ищет пользователя по имени и зашифрованному паролю в БД;

Все, что нужно для этого сделать - объявить бин PasswordEncoder, например, так:

```java
    @Bean
    private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
      return PasswordEncoderFactories.createDelegatingPasswordEncoder();
    }
```

Comment: Спасибо, попробовал изменить конфигурацию (обновления выше), но получаю 401

Comment: в постман передаю пароль в виде "test", в базе он хранится в sha256 - "9f86d081884c7d659a2feaa0c55ad015a3bf4f1b2b0b822cd15d6c15b0f00a08"

Comment: но если передать его в постман в зашифрованном виде, то запрос проходит

Comment: DaoAuthenticationProvider как bean явно объявлять не надо, он создается под капотом Spring Security. Объявленный напрямую как bean, AuthenticationProvider не попадает в контекст AuthenticationManager-а Spring Security. Вообщем, просто удалите его

Comment: удалил bean, все равно 401, я так понимаю, что spring шифрует входящий пароль, но также шифрует и уже зашифрованный в sha256 пароль из базы, и  в итоге сравнивает два разных результата. А я хотел бы, что спринг перевел входящий пароль в sha256 и сравнил его с паролем из базы, который уже хранится в sha256

Comment: Нет. Пароль в БД должен храниться уже в зашифрованном формате, это осуществляется в момент сохранения пользователя в БД, как правило, в прикладной логике. Этот пароль Spring-ом используется как есть. При попытке войти в систему пароль шифруется только 1 раз. Покажите код, который у вас связывает username/password запроса с проверкой пользователя в БД

Comment: userService.getUsers().forEach(user -> manager.createUser(createUserDetails(user.getUserName(), user.getPassword())));

Вот здесь, через InMemoryUserDetailsManager я добавляю юзеров которых вытащил из базы. UserService просто возвращает результат выполнения SELECT user_name, user_password FROM users

Comment: Кроме этого я больше ничего не делаю

Comment: Я имел ввиду как логин/пароль попадают из запроса в Spring Security. Эта логика должна быть где-то реализована: через фильтр, через самостоятельный API для получения токена

Comment: Хм, я предполагал, что срабатывает какой то прокси и спринг сам достает логин и пароль, при этом использует мою конфигурацию, которую я указал в вопросе. Просто я действительно больше ничего не делаю для работы Spring security) у меня нет фильтров и тд

Comment: Эти связующие фильтры не создаются автоматически. Spring Security создает только то, без чего он не работает и то, что он видит исходя из текущей конфигурации запуска. Посмотрите [BasicAuthenticationFilter](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/www/BasicAuthenticationFilter.html)

Comment: попробовал сделать как вы предложили, столкнулся с другой проблемой:
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1306945/spring-security-%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-username-%d0%b8%d0%b7-passwordencoder